# Assign different class for same div in while loop

Tags: php, class, loops, while-loop

I have code like below,

```
<?php
$sel_ms1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_milestone WHERE ms_status = 'Y' ORDER BY ms_pos ASC");

while ($sel_ms = mysqli_fetch_array($sel_ms1)) {  ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><span class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_year']; ?></span></td>
        <td class=''><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_desc']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

And I want to assign different class for second td like,

```
<tr>
 <td align="center"><span class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_year']; ?></span></td>
 <td class=''><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_desc']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="center"><span class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_year']; ?></span></td>
 <td class='error'><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_desc']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="center"><span class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_year']; ?></span></td>
 <td class=''><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_desc']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="center"><span class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_year']; ?></span></td>
 <td class='warning'><?php echo $sel_ms['ms_desc']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The above four will be looped respectively.
How can I achieve it through loop?

Comment: If the tablecell only requires styling based upon the class and the classname is not used programatically you could achive the alternating and repeating styles using pure css alone

Comment: Will the second row second td always have the error class, or is there some variable you should be checking?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$( "tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "error" ); 
$( "tr:nth-child(4n) td:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "warning" );
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, I do not think this is what is being asked for, if you read the question correctly, you'll see he  wants to do this within the loop. Not after the document has already been loaded.

Comment: @sandeep, nth-child is not possible.., Because in loop contain multi rows, i want to insert class frequently like order no 1 is Null class ,ordere no 2 is error class , order no 3 is Null class , order no 4 is warning class . These orders are repeating again and again .

Comment: $( "tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "error" );
$( "tr:nth-child(4n) td:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "warning" );

Please check it work fine and tested at my local machine.